# Python [Pyinstaller + modulo (cpuinfo) + PySimpleGui] Bucle infinito

Tags: python, pyinstaller

a ver si alguno puede hecharme una mano, me estoy haciendo un programilla para mi uso personal para ver ciertos parametros de mi CPU, con una interfaz gráfica, para ello utilizo los módulos (PysimpleGui y Cpuinfo), el programa funciona perfectamente sobre (Visual Studio). El problema viene a la hora de crear un archivo .EXE con Pyinstaller, crea el archivo .EXE, pero al ejecutarlo no se inicia y entra en un bucle infinito que pone el procesador al 100% y termina por bloquear el PC.

El problema lo causa el módulo (cpuinfo), con otros como (psutil) no hay este problema. En la pagina del desarrollador de (cpuinfo), el mismo desarrollador propone una solución para solucionar el problema del bucle infinito, el problema es que yo no se como integrarlo dentro del codigo de (PysimpleGui), si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria, gracias de antemano.

Dejo un simple ejemplo del codigo de (PysimpleGui) y el código a implementar para evitar el bucle a la hora de convertirlo a un archivo .EXE, con (Pyinstaller).

> Codigo PysimpleGui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import cpuinfo

Datos1=cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()["brand_raw"]
arreglo = str(Datos1)
  

sg.theme("DarkGreen 4")

layout = [[sg.Text("Parametros Básicos", font='verdana 15 bold')],
                [sg.Text("Procesador:   "+ arreglo, pad=((8,0),(20,0)))]]
                
                
                
window = sg.Window("", layout, size=(500, 500), no_titlebar=False, alpha_channel=1.0, finalize=True)


while True:
    event, values = window._ReadNonBlocking()

    if event == "Exit" or values is None:
        break
       
    elif event == 'close':
        window.close()
```

> Codigo (Cpuinfo) para solucionar el bucle (run under Pyinstaller)

```
# NOTE: Pyinstaller may spawn infinite processes if __main__ is not used
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from cpuinfo import get_cpu_info
    from multiprocessing import freeze_support

    # NOTE: Pyinstaller also requires freeze_support
    freeze_support()
    info = get_cpu_info()
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si sirve de informacion / solución para alguien con mi mismo problema, logré implementar la solución que propone el desarrollador de **(cpuinfo)** en mi proyecto para solucionar el bucle infinito, aun así, al convertir el archivo .py en un archivo .exe y ejecutarlo, este entra en bucle unas cuantas veces antes de finalmente ejecutarse.

Para una solucion temporal vale, pero no es muy atractivo visualmente que un programa entre en bucle varias veces antes de iniciarse. Dejo una solución alternativa, la sustitución del módulo **(cpuinfo)** por el módulo **(win32com.client)**, que permite acceder a las API's de Windows10 y obtener los datos que proporciona **(cpuinfo)** y muchos otros datos del sistema/hardware.

> Ejemplo para obtener el nombre de la cpu de nuestro equipo

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
    root_winmgmts = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    cpus = root_winmgmts.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
    return cpus[0].Name
```

Comment: puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta!

Comment: gracias por decirmelo, no sabia que eso se podia hacer, estoy mas verde, que una coliflor.